# How to get common object from a list of object based on a property?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

How do I combine two list based on similar properties. Let's say I have list A and List B. List A has Name property and List B has Name property. If the name of list A matches with the Name property of List B. Then save that object in a new list. How do I do this for the a number of lists that will be provided by user. So if user provides five lists. I want to get that object of all the objects whose property name matches. I can do it for two lists, using groupby but how to do it several lists?

```
 class Customer
{
     public int ID {get; set;}
     public string description {get; set;}
}



   List<Customer> AllCustomer; 
   var lst = new List<Hotel>();

         foreach (var item in AllCustomer)
            {


                var lst = CustomrBO.FetchSales(item);
            }
```

How do I get a list of Hotel's object if the HotelRegistration property of hotel matches for each customer?

```
               var resultSet = source.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                   .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                  .SelectMany(x => x);
```

Comment: I don't see how your code works with two lists. Also, it's going to be easier to answer if you add some sample classes

Comment: The question is kind of vague. Is it List<A. and List<B>? A and B are two different types that happen to share some properties that have the same same name? And your output is a list of objects that not only they have in common those properties, but also the same value of those properties?
Try add some examples of inputs and outputs.

Comment: Does List A have a `Name` property, or do the elements in List A all have a `Name` property?

Answer (score 0):

Well, why don't you join all those 5 lists user provides by using `List<T>.AddRange()` method and use the same process currently you are following

Comment: So each list can have objects with the same name property. If that name property exists in all the lists then take the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
    IList<Customer>  AllCustomers;
    IList<Hotel>      Hotels;

    var reg = from h in Hotels
              join c in AllCustomers on h.HotelRegistration equals c.Name
              select h;


}
class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

class Hotel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string HotelRegistration  { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it in one line code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var specialList = new List<C>();
        specialList.AddRange(listA.Where(x => ListB.Where(c => c.Name == x.Name).Any()).Select(x => new C()
        {
            Name = x.Name
        }));
    }
}

public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If you use of this code, yo will have many way to create your special object.
If you have question for many feature of this, comment me.